# Values not returned in PDO fetchAll command

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to retrieve first four rows, the second grooup of four rows and so on until the end of the MySQL table named Productos. If I make queries from PHPMyAdmin values are retrieved correctly. But when I try to retrieve them from PHP no values are retrieved.

The code:

```
$this -> minimo = $_GET["minimo"];
echo "</br>" . $this -> minimo;

$this -> qry = "SELECT nombre,descripcion,precio,foto FROM productos       
LIMIT ?,4";
$this -> sqry = $this -> conexion -> prepare($this -> qry);
$this->sqry->bindParam(1,$this -> minimo,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$this -> sqry -> execute();

echo "</br>"; var_dump($this -> sqry);

$this -> resul = $this -> sqry -> fetchAll();

echo "Resul es " ; var_dump($this -> resul);
```

After running the script I watch the following:

```
0

object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) { 
        ["queryString"]=> string(62) "SELECT nombre,descripcion,precio,foto FROM productos LIMIT ?,4" }

Resul es array(0) { }
```

How can I retrive values?

Thanks

Comment: Is it suppose to be `$this -> resul` and not `$this -> result`?

Comment: Then you should `LIMIT 4`

Comment: People take time out of their day to help. Show some support and accept answers on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using lazy loading i.e. an array in the execute parameter

```
$this -> sqry -> execute(array($this -> minimo));
```

All parameters are treated as strings, which will generate

```
LIMIT '1', 4
```

And `'1'` is illegal syntax

So you have to specifiy the type like this

```
$this->minimo = $_GET["minimo"];
$this->qry = "SELECT nombre,descripcion,precio,foto FROM productos LIMIT ?,4";
$this->sqry = $this->conexion->prepare($this->qry);
$this->sqry->bindParam(1, $this->minimo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$this->sqry->execute();
$this->resul = $this->sqry->fetchAll();

// now $this->resul should be an array of arrays unless 
// you have set PDO up to return Object by default
// so a simple print_r() should show you whats in the returned data
print_r($this->resul);
```

Alternatively you can turn off Emulated Prepares as part of your connection and continue using the Lazy Load method

```
$this->conexion->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );

$this->minimo = $_GET["minimo"];
$this->qry = "SELECT nombre,descripcion,precio,foto FROM productos LIMIT ?,4";
$this->sqry = $this -> conexion -> prepare($this -> qry);
$this->sqry->execute(array($this -> minimo));

$this->resul = $this -> sqry -> fetchAll();
```

> If you just want the first 4 rows you could use `LIMIT 4` but it would probably be a good idea to add an `ORDER BY` to make sure you get the correct first 4 rows maybe like this `LIMIT 4 ORDER BY id`

Comment: Thanks for answering but it doesn't run it. There aren't errors but when I want to know the values of resul and $this -> minimo appear messages I updated in the question.

Comment: Ok, if you only want 4 rows, try changing the query to just use `LIMIT 4` and see if the query returns real row data

Comment: Yes, it runs. I can watch first four rows. But I want to get the following four rows, and the following four ... until the end of the table

Comment: I just try the second option and what I watch are the first four rows although I change minimo. I insert values 0,4 and 8 and I always watch the first four rows. When I make the query in phpMyAdmin results are right.

Comment: It works. Finally I type $this->conexion->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false ); and I can watch four rows depending on minimo value.The second option you type is right.